# How do I draw a line from a set of points in unity to use as terrain in a 2D game?

Tags: unity

I'm trying to make a 2D game in unity. My terrain is randomly generated and what I'm trying to do is make a bunch of points with different x coordinates and then draw a line through them to use as my ground/terrain.

Originally I wanted to make a polygon out of the points by specifying two additional vertices which would basically be the camera bounds and fill the whole thing in, but I'm not sure that's feasible, so I'll settle for just having a line as a platform.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: If your points would not create concave shapes then you should look up convex decomposition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two different solutions in your case:

1. The easy one: take a look at [LineRenderer](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-LineRenderer.html)
2. The "hard" one: [build your own mesh](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.html)

Comment: Are they both just as viable if I want to use them for collision detection?

Comment: Oh, in case of collision detection, I'd say you should probably prefere to build your own mesh and apply a [MeshCollider](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MeshCollider.html) on it.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. I'll be implementing my own physics and collision detection without using any of unity's built in physics/colliders. Now that I think about it... I guess it won't matter. Anyway thanks for the help. I've already started playing with the LineRenderer

Comment: you can also use GL.LINES http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GL.LINES.html